# How o return a Json field from a Unirest request

Tags: jira, unirest

Using postman to test a request I have the following return Json response

```
{
"@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users(externalUserState)/$entity",
"externalUserState": "Accepted"
```

}

Now from my Unirest same API call, I need to return the value of **externalUserState**

What I am doing is the following

```
def result = get(graph_base_user_url + userId + "?")
         .header("Authorization","Bearer " + AuthToken )
         .queryString("\$select","ExternalUserState")
         .asJson()
         
         return result.getBody()
```

but could not reach the way to fetch the string "Accepted"

Any idea what could be wrong ?

regards

Answer (score 0):

I find it out by using the result.getBody().getObject().getString("ExternalUserState")